# DrawPDFPage causes a SIGSEV crash when opening a raster PDF in iOS 10

Tags: pdf, xamarin, linker, xamarin.ios, core-graphics

Whenever I call CoreGraphics.CGContext.DrawPDFPage() with a raster (scanned) pdf I immediately get a crash in iOS 10. The same pdf does not cause a crash on an iOS 9 device. The error is a SIGSEV:

> Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates a
>   fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries  used
>   by your application.

However, if I set my linker to "Don't link" the pdf opens fine. When it is set to "link all" or "link framework sdks only" I get the crash. I can't switch to "don't link" due to app size constaints, so I tried adding "--linkskip=Xamarin.iOS" to the additional mtouch arguments, but then I got an error when building:

> "Error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException <filepath>.nib does not
>   exist".

Is there a bug in DrawPDFPage? Is it possible to linkskip Xamarin.iOS? If so, what can I do to fix the FileNotFoundException?

Comment: Link skipping Xamarin.iOS should be essentially the same as using the "Don't link" option, so that is a non-starter. That said I tried to reproduce this issue. I used the code here to test: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.CoreGraphics.CGContext.DrawPDFPage/p/MonoTouch.CoreGraphics.CGPDFPage/#Remarks . Using a scanned pdf page, the first page of the document rendered fine on my iOS 10 iPhone (iPhone 6s). Could you share your code or perhaps the exact pdf file you are using? Also make sure you are on latest stable version of Xamarin.iOS and XCode 8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be an bug in iOS 10 itself as the same PDF caused the same error in a native Obj-C Xcode project.